# A list of Python Hooks?

Tags: python, hook

To better understand a program I'm trying to implement a tracing metaclass, that when a class inherits from it all its method calls get traced to a file.  I can't simply use a module like `Trace.py` because I don't have access to a console in my execution environment.  I recently learned about `sys.settrace()`, a hook that gets called whenever python executes a line, and while it almost solves my problem I can't get relevant line information for the trace because I don't have any way to knowing which file will be executed.  I suspect I need a hook that gets called right before any method in a class gets called, that passes in the method name, and then implement that hook in the tracing metaclass.

Is there a reference somewhere of all the python hooks?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question properly, but you can get information about file/line from the `f_code` member of the frame:

```
def trace(frame, event, arg_frame):
    print(frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_code.co_firstlineno)

sys.settrace(trace)
```

More info about the frame and code objects: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html